# Deselect key of the current frame located on the timeline

Tags: python, maya, mel

Of the keys that are selected, deselect only those that are in the current animation frame.

The code selects the current key and one before and one after the current time, I just need to deselect the one that is currently located on the timeline and I don't know how to do it.

Here is a video example of how I want it to be deselected.
[image]

```
keyA = mc.currentTime(q = True)
ttA = mc.findKeyframe(t = (keyA,keyA), w = "previous")
ttB = mc.findKeyframe(t = (keyA,keyA), w = "next")

cmds.selectKey(animation='objects',add=False,t=(ttA,ttB))
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you can tell what's wrong. I suppose your code does not work, but I'm not sure. Did you try the `toggle` flag?

Comment: The code selects the current key and one before and one after the current time, I just need to deselect the one that is currently located on the timeline and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Here is the answer, the solution

`import maya.cmds as mc
keyA = mc.currentTime(q = True)
mc.selectKey(animation = 'objects', k = True,time = (keyA,keyA), rm = True)`

Comment: @FenixAnimator You can post that as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer, the solution

```py
import maya.cmds as mc 
keyA = mc.currentTime(q = True) 
mc.selectKey(animation = 'objects', k = True,time = (keyA,keyA), rm = True)
```